# How big android applications like Amazon , Flipkart , Myntra has very less cache though they load a lot of images? Where do they store images?

Tags: android, performance, caching, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I am developing an android application , How so ever it has memory issues for Kitkat devices. How do these firms do to optimize their memory usage?

Answer (score 0):

They will only load a low resolution image as a preview that fits exactly the size of the element. This is also stated on the Android Developer Page. I would suggest you to follow [this training](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) and see if it helps you.

> Given that you are working with limited memory, ideally you only want to load a lower resolution version in memory. The lower resolution version should match the size of the UI component that displays it. An image with a higher resolution does not provide any visible benefit, but still takes up precious memory and incurs additional performance overhead due to additional on the fly scaling.